# .net core 3.1 HostBuilder not having RunAsServiceAsync method (IHostBuilder does not contain definition for RunAsServiceAsync)

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, ihostedservice

I have .net core 3.1 console application and I want to run it as a windows service, my program.cs looks like

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

            var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args);

            if (isService)
            {
                await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker1>();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();
                });
    }
```

and the .csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-MyWorkerService-16487890-DF99-45C2-8DC4-5475A21D6B75</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.1.16" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

but for RunAsServiceAsync() error is coming like "IHostBuilder does not contain definition for RunAsServiceAsync"

Can anyone please point to me where / what I am missing?

Comment: Are you using some 3rd part library that has `RunAsServiceAsync` as an extension on `IHostBuilder`? That is the only thing I see possible as that function is not native to .net core

Comment: Found this in one of their examples. Could probably implement it your self https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1da228d28fdfcfb2d77241c4e0413efec1beeafd/samples/GenericHostSample/ServiceBaseLifetime.cs#L18

Comment: @Nkosi I saw many .net core windows services examples online that have RunAsServiceAsync so thought it is native to .net core, thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RunAsServiceAsync` appears to be 3rd party extension on `IHostBuilder`.

It does not appear to be a built in function, native to .NET Core.

I found an old implementation on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1da228d28fdfcfb2d77241c4e0413efec1beeafd/samples/GenericHostSample/ServiceBaseLifetime.cs#L18) that you could probably implement yourself

```
public static class ServiceBaseLifetimeHostExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder UseServiceBaseLifetime(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
        return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, ServiceBaseLifetime>());
    }

    public static Task RunAsServiceAsync(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return hostBuilder.UseServiceBaseLifetime().Build().RunAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class ServiceBaseLifetime : ServiceBase, IHostLifetime
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _delayStart = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    public ServiceBaseLifetime(IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(applicationLifetime));
    }

    private IApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

    public Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.Register(() => _delayStart.TrySetCanceled());
        ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(Stop);

        new Thread(Run).Start(); // Otherwise this would block and prevent IHost.StartAsync from finishing.
        return _delayStart.Task;
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            Run(this); // This blocks until the service is stopped.
            _delayStart.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException("Stopped without starting"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _delayStart.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Stop();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Called by base.Run when the service is ready to start.
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _delayStart.TrySetResult(null);
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    // Called by base.Stop. This may be called multiple times by service Stop, ApplicationStopping, and StopAsync.
    // That's OK because StopApplication uses a CancellationTokenSource and prevents any recursion.
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

But it appears that this service based functionality is now built in when `UseWindowsService` is called on the builder.

So in that case you would need to refactor your code accordingly to get the desired behavior

```
public class Program {
    public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

        var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args);

        if (isService) {
            await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
        } else {
            await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker1>();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();
            });
}

public static class ServiceBaseLifetimeHostExtensions {
    public static Task RunAsServiceAsync(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        return hostBuilder.UseWindowsService().Build().RunAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```